# awk shell script to process a csv file with double quotes

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file with the following format.

```
event1,event2,event3,event4  
"Ozz","time","1234","test1"  
"Max","time1","5678","test2"
```

I need to replace the first columns value without changing the header.
And I need the second columns value copied in to the third column. 
So the expected output is:

```
event1,event2,event3,event4  
"Razor","time","time","test1"  
"Maxine","time1","time1","test2"
```

Output will be to another csv file
I am not sure how to go about this ?

Comment: *I need to replace the first columns value* with what?

Comment: Say the first value is Ozz needs to be replaced by a value specified on the program. like Ozz replaced with Razor and Max replaced with Maxine.

Comment: what if there is some other value other than Razor

Comment: Irrespective of whatever is in the first value. I am trying to substitue/replace with a defined value

Comment: So how about the answer i just added. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it needs to add the first column value manually for each row. @Where the names you want to add was located?

Comment: I believe your question has some typos.  Please correct them. "5678: should be "5678", and "time1: should be "time1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use somthing like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1~/^".*"$/{gsub("^\"Ozz\"$", "\"Razor\"",$1); gsub("^\"Max\"$","\"Maxine\"", $1); $3=$2;print $0} /event/' inputFile
```

giving outpu as

```
 event1,event2,event3,event4
"Razor","time","time","test1"
"Maxine","time1","time1","test2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. How to run this a program ?

Comment: @DeepakG replace the `inputFile` with the csv file name

Comment: i am able to run this command and get the results as shown.May be my question is not clear.  How to run this as a shell script ? I am looking to run this periodically in a directory where csv files are getting dumped ?

Comment: If you want to schedule a script periodically, `cron ` is will help you. read the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: This output doesnt have the headers in it

Comment: @DeepakG i have corrected to involve header as well

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small (less then 100 lines) using pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is a good alternative:

```
exec 3<inputfile
read -ru 3 a; echo $a
while IFS=, read -ru 3 v a b b; do
    v=${v/#\"/};v=${v/%\"/} # Trim surrounding "
    case $v in
    Ozz) v=Razor;;
    Max) v=Maxine;;
    *) echo "Wrong value '$v'">&2; v=Default;;
    esac
    echo "\"$v\",$a,$a,$b"
done
```

Output:

```
event1,event2,event3,event4
"Razor","time","time","test1"
"Maxine","time1","time1","test2"
```

The replacement could be read from another file and a hash could be used for the replacement.